# Fastest way to filter for certain keys from dictionaries which are stored in a list of dictionaries which is in turn stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, filtering

I am looking for the fastest way to filter for certain keys from "inner" dictionaries inside lists inside an "outer" dictionary, so kind of a tricky data structure.

The data structure (input) looks like this: All inner dictionaries have the same keys but the lists can have different numbers of dictionaries.

```
d = {1:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}],
 2:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}],
 3:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}]}
```

What I want as output is the same structure but only the inner dictionary keys 1 and 2, I don't need 3 and 4 anymore:

```
d_new = {1: [{1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}],
 2: [{1: 33, 2: 33}],
 3: [{1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}]}
```

So far, I have two approaches which solve the problem but are very slow:

1. Combination of list- and dict comprehension:

```
d_new = {n: [{1: d[1], 2: d[2]} for d in d[n]] for n in d.keys()}
```

2. For-Loop

```
d_new = {}

keys = d.keys()

for key in keys:
    storage = []
    for x in d[key]:
        storage.append({1: x[1], 2: x[2]})
    d_new[key] = storage
```

They both solve the problem but are very slow when applied to large dictionaries so
I am looking for a faster and more efficient way, maybe it is also possible to apply some kind of paralellization here. Very happy for any help!

Comment: In the dictionary `d` you have duplicate key `3`. Is that correct?

Comment: the second "3" as outer_dict key was just an error, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

### The Code

```py
from copy import deepcopy

d = {1:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}],
 2:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}],
 3:[{1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}, {1:33 ,2:33, 3:33, 4:33}]}

d_new = deepcopy(d) #Done so that we don't run into issues with list items

d_items = list(d_new.items())
for i in d_items:
    for j in i[1]:
        pop_l = [] #Created a list of entries to pop since popping them while in the for loop changes the loop length and gives a runtime error
        for k in j:
            if k > 2:
                pop_l.append(k)
        for x in pop_l: #Popping all unwanted keys
            j.pop(x)

print(d_new)
```

### Output

```py
{1: [{1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}], 2: [{1: 33, 2: 33}], 3: [{1: 33, 2: 33}, {1: 33, 2: 33}]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Unfortunately, deepcopy is extremely slow and I also need to keep the old dictionary in addition to the new one. Maybe I can check out your loop with a json/pickle loads-dump workaround. Is popping keys generally faster that copying them? the second "3" as outer_dict key was just an error, I edited the question.

Comment: I ran some test on the pop-approach, it seems to give me a >25% speed-up compared to my own for-loop when using shallow copy (copy.copy(d)) instead of deepcopy. Other things I have tried were ujson.loads(ujson.dumps(d)), json.loads(json.dumps(d)), pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(d, -1)), cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(d, -1)) which were all by far faster than deep copy but still way too slow for my application (I need to process a very large dictionary very very often...)

Comment: The problem is, I cannot work with shallow copy since it messes up my original dictionary.

Comment: Multithreading can be used to speed up the task. I will need some time to build up the code.